# Error while fetching from mongo for XMLGregorianCalendar conversion - Spring Data Mongo

Tags: xml, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc

I'm using HATEOS with spring data mongo !
Getting error while trying to fetch data -

```
2017-01-23 13:31:43.859  INFO 13108 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:9179}] to hkl101632.hk.hsbc:5255
2017-01-23 13:31:44.672 ERROR 13108 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar using constructor public javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar() with arguments ] with root cause

java.lang.InstantiationException: null
    at sun.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:48) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.convert.ReflectionEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ReflectionEntityInstantiator.java:76) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.convert.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:83) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:252) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:232) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1197) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.access$200(MappingMongoConverter.java:79) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1145) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.getValueInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:871) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:284) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:272) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

I'm able to push the data with xml to pojo mapping, but while retriving, it is not able to pull data from mongo as it tries to convert for XMLGregorianCalendar instance !

Can we write a root level converter without changing existing xml-pojo mapping to convert and save the datetime instance with java.util.Date .

Below is my sample code !

XML input while saving :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Entity>
        <Header>
            <MsgId>12345wqw</MsgId>
            <DateTimeField>2009-09-28T14:07:00</DateTimeField>
            <Info>
                <Name>Some Name</Name>
                <Address>
                    <StrtNm>Times Square</StrtNm>
                    <BldgNb>7</BldgNb>
                    <PstCd>NY 10036</PstCd>
                    <TwnNm>New York</TwnNm>
                    <Ctry>US</Ctry>
                </Address>
            </Info>
        </Header>
    </Entity>
</Document>
```

Mapped Pojo :

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Header", propOrder = {"msgId", "DateTimeField", "Info"})
public class GroupHeader48 {

    @XmlElement(name = "MsgId", required = true)
    protected String msgId;

    @XmlElement(name = "DateTimeField", required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar creDtTm;

    @XmlElement(name = "Info", required = true)
    protected Information info;


    public String getMsgId() {
        return this.msgId;
    }


    public void setMsgId(final String value) {
        this.msgId = value;
    }


    public XMLGregorianCalendar getCreDtTm() {
        return this.creDtTm;
    }


    public void setCreDtTm(final XMLGregorianCalendar value) {
        this.creDtTm = value;
    }

    public Information getInfo() {
        return this.info;
    }


    public void setInitgPty(final Information value) {
        this.info = value;
    }
}
```

I've also tried using adapters, but i have many pojos where the datetime field is used and cannot control changing the mapping as it comes from another process